# using the result of subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

how can i use the result of a subquery inside its parent query?

my code look like this.

```
select (select count(*) from tbl1 group by field) as result1, 
       (select count(*) from tbl2 group by field) as result2, 
       (select count(*) from tbl3 group by field) as result3,
       result1 + result2 - result3 as total1,
       result1 + result2  as total2 
 from tbl4 ;
```

some suggest to direct add the subquery .

```
(select count(*)*....) as result1 + (select count(*)*....) as result2
```

but i think its not want i need, bcoz i need also to display/maintain  the value of result1 in my result.

is there somebody who can help me, i badly need this to work out, i appreciate every help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: The resultant table what you need, please show that, since, what you need, is not clear

Comment: result: if result1 is 3, result2 is 2, result3 is 4, then the total1 will be 1 (result1 + result2 - result3)

Comment: @avien: then what is wrong with your query?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to wrap your query in a subselect to be able to access the aliased column names:

```
SELECT a.result1 + a.result2 - a.result3 AS total1,
       a.result1 + a.result2 AS total2
  FROM (
            select (select count(*) from tbl1 group by field) as result1, 
                   (select count(*) from tbl2 group by field) as result2,
                   (select count(*) from tbl3 group by field) as result3
       ) a
```

But this would actually be a much better solution:

```
    SELECT a.cnt + b.cnt - c.cnt AS total1, 
           a.cnt + b.cnt AS total2
      FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM tbl1 GROUP BY field) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM tbl2 GROUP BY field) b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM tbl3 GROUP BY field) c
```

Comment: i forget to tell all my subquery is depending on my my tbl4 like this (select (count(*) from tbl1 group by field where tbl1.field = tbl4.field)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your sub query will return a set. So just use the following---

`SELECT column1, column2, column3 
FROM table1 
WHERE column3 IN (SELECT column3 
FROM table2 WHERE condition);`

Answer (score 0):

```
select count1, count2, count3, 
  count1+count2-count3 as total1, count1+count2 as total2 
  from tbl4 
inner join 
  (select count(*) as count1,name from tbl1 group by name)as result1 
on tbl4.name=result1.name 
inner join 
   (select count(*)as count2,name from tbl2 group by name) as result2
on tbl4.name=result2.name 
inner join 
   (select count(*)as count3,name from tbl3 group by name) as result3
on tbl4.name=result3.name
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this query and let me know

```
 select result1.cnt,result2.cnt,result2.cnt,result1.cnt + 
  result2.cnt - result3.cnt as total1,
  result1.cnt + result2.cnt  as total2   
  from
 (select field,COUNT(*) cnt from tbl1 group by field) as result1 
  join
 (select field,COUNT(*) cnt from tbl2 group by field) as result2
 on result1.field=result2.field
 join
 (select field,COUNT(*) cnt from tbl3 group by field) as result3
 on result3.field=result2.field
 join tbl4
 on tbl1.field = tbl4.field
```